# How to use dependencies in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl

I have two Api Api's. One use data from the other and both are already in Kubernetes.

I've already read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838141/how-can-we-create-service-dependencies-using-kubernetes) about creating service dependencies using Kubernetes, but I don't understand well.

The question is, how can I create a dependency on `kubectl` create and run my 2 API?
One important thing to say, I'm using Helm Chart.

Comment: What are you asking that's different from the question you linked to?  Kubernetes doesn't have any concept of "dependencies"; but you will generally know the other Service's name (especially if the same Helm chart is deploying both) and can try to call it, failing if it's not there.

Comment: @DavidMaze do you have any hint how can I call a service ?

Comment: The Kubernetes documentation has a [Connect a Front End to a Back End Using a Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/connecting-frontend-backend/) example.

Comment: You should be able to consume the service using the endpoint `servicename.namespace.svc.cluster.local`....if both apps lives in the same namespace, you should be able to consume it just using the service name as an endpoint `serviceName`...also you can check it using `curl`