# configuration of readiness probe for my webapp

Tags: kubernetes

I am running a sample webapp python in Kubernetes.
I am not able to figure out how I make use of probes here.

1. I want app to recover from broken states by automatically restarting pods
2. Route the traffic to the healthy pods only.
3. Make sure the database is up and running before the application (which in my case is Redis).

I have understanding of probes but not sure how/what values exactly to look for

My definition file:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-deployment
  labels:
     env: production
     app: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      env: production
      app: frontend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: myapp-pod 
      labels:
        env: production
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp-container
        image: myimage:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
```

Now I am doing something like this

```
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /
            port: 5000
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 5
        livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /
          port: 5000
        intialDelaySeconds: 10
        periodSeconds: 5
```

Comment: Are you using Helm or Kubectl as a client?

Comment: as of I am doing it using kubectl , later once I have project ready then will create helm chart for the whole

Comment: Hi Waseem, were you able to run probes for your python app and redis using the suggested methods?

Comment: Hi Waseem, 
Consider [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) one of the answers if it answers your initial question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define both

- `readinessProbe`: allowing to tell whether your `Deployment` is ready to serve traffic at any point of time during its lifecycle. This configuration item can support different command but in your case, this would be an `httpGet` matching and endpoint that you would implement in your web-app (most modern stack define the endpoints by default so check check the documentation of whatever framework you are using). Note that the endpoint handler would need to check the **readiness** of any needed dependency, in your case you would need to check if `http[s]://redis-host:redis-port` responds with success
- `livenessProbe`: allowing for the control plane to check continuously your pods health and to decide on actions needed to get the cluster to the desired state rolling out any pods failing to report being alive. This probe support different definitions as well and as for the `readinessProbe` most modern framework offer endpoints responding to such request by default

Here down you can see a sample of both probes, for which you would have two respective HTTP endpoints within your web application:

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-deployment
  labels:
     env: production
     app: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      env: production
      app: frontend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: myapp-pod 
      labels:
        env: production
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp-container
        image: myimage:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
      readinessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /health
          port: 5000
      livenessProbe:
        httpGet:
          path: /health
          port: 5000
```

Comment: will this work as is or I will have make changes to it?

Comment: I got this error while I used this probe 
`Warning  Unhealthy  0s (x11 over 50s)  kubelet            Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 404`

Comment: I forgot to mention the application is in python

Comment: I have mentioned in my answer that you need to have an endpoint (HTTP route) in your application that responds with successful (200 OK) HTTP response after having verified the datastore (redis) being up.

Answer (score 0):

In Kubernetes you have three kind of probes:

- Liveness - is my application still running? If this fails the application is restarted
- Readiness - is my application ready to serve traffic? If this fails the current pod does not get traffic (e.g. via a service).
- Startup (since 1.18) - this probe type was introduces for applications that need a long time to start. The other two probe types start after the startup probe reports success the first time.

So, in your case your application should provide one probe that checks if it still running and another if it can server traffic (also checking Redis). Be aware the [liveness probes may be dangerous](https://srcco.de/posts/kubernetes-liveness-probes-are-dangerous.html) - maye start only with a readiness probe.

If your app provides the health check (incl. Redis) under `/healthz`, this is how you would define your readiness probe.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myapp-deployment
  labels:
     env: production
     app: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      env: production
      app: frontend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: myapp-pod 
      labels:
        env: production
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp-container
        image: myimage:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        readinessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /healthz
            port: 5000
          initialDelaySeconds: 3
          periodSeconds: 3
```

Comment: My app is very simple app, which is basic hello world. it does not provide /healthz.
I have also read that /healthz is deprecated ?

Comment: Why should /healthz be deprecated - this is framework/app specific.

Comment: If you do not have an health endpoint just use "/"

Answer (score 0):

As we know, there are  Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes in Kubernetes. Check the official [Kubernetes Documentation page on this topic](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).

The Kubelet Node agent can perform these probes on running Pods using 3 different methods:

- HTTP: The Kubelet probe performs an HTTP GET request against an endpoint (like  `/health`), and succeeds if the response status is between 200 and 399
- Container Command: The Kubelet probe executes a command inside of the running container. If the exit code is 0, then the probe succeeds.
- TCP: The Kubelet probe attempts to connect to your container on a specified port. If it can establish a TCP connection, then the probe succeeds.

> I am running a sample webapp python in Kubernetes. I am not able to figure out how I make use of probes here.
>
> #### 1.  I want app to recover from broken states by automatically restarting pods.    2.  Route the traffic to the healthy pods only.

For this you should use both the readiness and liveness probes.  They can both use the same probe method and perform the same check, but the inclusion of a readiness probe will ensure that the Pod doesn’t receive traffic until the probe begins succeeding.

For example you can add minimal health endpoint for a flask python app like this:

```
@app.route('/health')
def return_ok():
    return 'Ok!', 200
```

And specify your k8s liveness and readiness probe like this:

```yaml
...
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp-container
        image: myimage:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
        readinessProbe:                      # extra section for your Deployment 
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 5000
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 5
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: /health
            port: 5000
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 5                  # end of the section
```

If you wish you can define a **liveness probe command** (replace the extra section):

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - cat
    - /tmp/healthy
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 5
```

To perform a probe, the kubelet executes the command  `cat /tmp/healthy`  in the target container. If the command succeeds, it returns 0, and the kubelet considers the container to be alive and healthy. If the command returns a non-zero value, the kubelet kills the container and restarts it.

Another option is to define a **TCP liveness/readiness probe**:

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  tcpSocket:
    port: 5000
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 5
```

This will attempt to connect to the your container on port 5000. If the probe succeeds, the Pod will be marked as ready.

> #### 3.  Make sure the database is up and running before the application (which in my case is Redis).

And for checking health of Redis pods you can put a bash script file in your Redis pod to /health/ping_liveness_local.sh:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
[[ -f $REDIS_PASSWORD_FILE ]] && export REDIS_PASSWORD="$(< "${REDIS_PASSWORD_FILE}")"
[[ -n "$REDIS_PASSWORD" ]] && export REDISCLI_AUTH="$REDIS_PASSWORD"
response=$(
 timeout -s 3 $1 \
 redis-cli \
  -h localhost \
  -p $REDIS_PORT \
  ping 
)
if [ $? == 124 ]; then
 echo "Timed out"
 exit 1
fi
responseFirstWord=$(echo $response | head -n1 | awk '{print $1;}')
if [ "$response" != "PONG" ] && [ "$responseFirstWord" != "LOADING" ] && [ "$responseFirstWord" != "MASTERDOWN" ]; then
 echo "$response"
 exit 1
fi
```

and use this section for your redis pods:

```yaml
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command: 
    - sh 
    - -c 
    - /health/ping_liveness_local.sh 5
  failureThreshold: 5
  initialDelaySeconds: 20
  periodSeconds: 5
  successThreshold: 1
  timeoutSeconds: 6
```

If this seems too complicated, then I suggest installing [Redis packaged by Bitnami](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/redis). It is very easy to install it on a Kubernetes cluster using the [Helm](https://helm.sh/) package manager.
Bitnami guys configured all needed liveness and readiness probes for Redis.

Regarding **how to ensure that DB is up and running before your application**, check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50838829/17739440), please. This solution uses K8s [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).