# Kubernetes - waiting on Oracle DB container

Tags: kubernetes, containers

Apologies for a basic question. I have a simple Kubernetes deployment where I have 3 containers (each in their own pod) deployed to a Kubernetes cluster.

The `RESTapi` container is dependent upon the `OracleDB` container starting. However, the `OracleDB` container takes a while to startup and by that time the `RESTapi` container has restarted a number of times due to not being able to connect and ends up in a `Backoff` state.

Is there a more elegant solution for this?

I’ve also noticed that when the `RESTapi` container goes into the `Backoff` state it stops retrying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is a community wiki answer posted for better visibility. Feel free to expand it.*

The best approach in this case is to improve your “RESTapi” application to provide a more reliable and fault-tolerant service that will allow it reconnect to the database anyway.

From [Kubernetes
production
best practices](https://github.com/learnk8s/kubernetes-production-best-practices/blob/dfebcd934ee6d6a6b8c4b8f7aa3cfad9a980f592/application-development.md#the-app-retries-connecting-to-dependent-services):

> When the app starts, it shouldn't crash because a dependency such as a
> database isn't ready.
>
> Instead, the app should keep retrying to connect to the database until
> it succeeds.
>
> Kubernetes expects that application components can be started in any
> order.

In other case you can use solution with [Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/).

You can look at this [question on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50838141/how-can-we-create-service-dependencies-using-kubernetes), which is just one of many others about the practical use of Init Containers for the case described.

Answer (score 0):

An elegant way to achieve this is by using a combination of [Kubernetes Init Containers](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) paired with [k8s-wait-for](https://github.com/groundnuty/k8s-wait-for) scripts.

Essentially, what you would do is configure an Init Container for your RESTapi which uses k8s-wait-for. You configure k8s-wait-for to wait for a specific pod to be in a given state, in this case, you can provide the OracleDB pod and wait for it to be in a Ready state.

The resulting effect will be that the deployment of the RESTapi will be paused until the OracleDB is ready to go. That should alleviate the constant restarts.

https://github.com/groundnuty/k8s-wait-for